# Javascript - TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called `arr` with objects nested inside of it as seen in the example below:

```
[{"type" : "space", "content" : "value", /*etc.*/},
{"type" : "space", "content" : "value", /*etc.*/},
{"type" : "other value", "content" : "value", /*etc.*/},
 /*Other nested objects*/
];
```

So i'm trying to loop through the array to check if the object after the one that the loop is currently "focused" on contains the 'type' property then check if it's type property is set to "space", if it is it will remove it from the array

This is the bit of code that is turning up the type error:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i].type && arr[i + 1].type){
    if (arr[a].type == "space" && arr[a + 1].type == "space"){
      arr.pop(arr[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong as it does not seem to be happy with the `arr[i + 1]` on the second line

Please ask if you would like me to expand on anything that I have not made clear.
Many thanks.

Comment: `arr.pop()` alters the array and its size while the loop is still iterating over it. This may lead to unexpected results, like index `i+1` not being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
```

as you access i+1, you need to stop iterating earlier...

Also Array.pop always removes the last element. You want to splice:

```
arr.splice(i,1);
i--;//keep index at the right position
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much I was about to use this use this unnecessary and complicated solution, but this is much better, I will accept answer as correct as soon as i'm allowed to.

Comment: If you "walk" backwards and check elements `i` and `i - 1` you won't have to adjust the index after removal. You could also use `Array.prototype.filter()`: https://jsfiddle.net/z1jttuxh/

Comment: @Andreas that lets the first element stay, the OP wants the last element

Comment: The solutions will work the same way. You just have to tweak some values. Instead of `.splice(a, 1)` it would be `.splice(a - 1, 1)` (https://jsfiddle.net/4cesce0u/) and the `.filter()` solution (with two adjustments) would be: https://jsfiddle.net/yn5k27uj/.